# ORA-02289:sequence does not exist

Tags: c#, oracle, fluent-nhibernate

I am using `FluentNHibernate`, I have a method that takes the JSON post makes a deserialize for the class type and saved it, and after is suppose to make a commit but I am getting the errors on save,

```
using (ITransaction transacao = _session.BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel.ReadCommitted))
{
  _session.Save(cameras);
  transacao.Commit();
}
```

the name of my class already equals the name on the bank, this is my mapping builder.

```
public MapCAMERAS()
{
  Id(i => i.C_CAM);
  Map(c => c.C_BAL);
  Map(c => c.A_CAM);
  Map(c => c.D_CAM);
  Map(c => c.E_CAM);
  Map(c => c.N_CAM);
  Map(c => c.P_CAM);
  Map(c => c.S1_CAM);
  Map(c => c.S2_CAM);
  Map(c => c.T_CAM);
  Map(c => c.U_CAM);
  Map(c => c.DUMANUT);
}
```

I check the names in table, all names are correct and I just have C_CAM as Id.
For use this application is not necessary authentication.
I have one Repository and I make my save method there, and service with method calling my Repository, on my post I'm using MVC.

```
var service = new ServiceCamera(new RepositoryCamera(session));
var result = new RespostaPost();
result = servico.Gravar(cameras);
```

Error: 
[image]

My error is when I make the post method. How can I fix this error?

Comment: If your error is `ORA-02289:sequence does not exist` then the error message says all! There must be a trigger to get the next id for this table from a [sequence](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/pseudocolumns002.htm), but there's no such sequence defined in the database!

Comment: Unrelated, but you've got a duplicate mapping for `Map(c => c.S_CAM);`

Comment: Have you tried looking at some [other posts](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=sequence+does+not+exist)?

Comment: Please edit your post and include the complete text of the error(s) you're getting. Thanks.

Comment: @StuartLC not is duplicated, I left the first letter of the name of tablemas, my mistake. sory

Comment: @ericbn yes i google before asking, I found the documentation of the oracle was more a problem in being identified where I am missing

Comment: @ericbn in this table i just have one trigger for check if date is null, if is i set the current date, and untill insert i make one create or update.

Comment: Sorry, but for some reason I can't see included images. I suspect it's either a Chrome or a firewall thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### **Solution**

Very simple. Possibly you mapping not config the increment type.

---

Try some like this:

```
Id(i => i.TableId).GeneratedBy.Increment();
```